# Port-forwarding on a linux cluster

Tags: port-forwarding

I am on a university cluster.  The login nodes have a connection to the internet, however, the cluster nodes do not.  How can I route traffic from the compute cluster to the login node (via the internal network)?

Comment: Please add a truck load more information.  This is impossible to answer as is.

Comment: Ask the IT staff.